# Convert tab separated excel to autofiltered HTML

Tags: html, excel, autofilter

I want to convert excel tables exported in tab separated form into HTML files (with Javascript) that support autofilter combo on the column headings, at least on single values.
I.e. when I select discrete values from (each of) some of the combo boxes, only the matching lines are displayed.

Is there any freely available solution to generate such HTML, preferably a script ?

(In case of negative answer, I'm planning to write something in Python for that...)

Comment: it should be possible to load the text file into an invisible iframe and read its contents with javascript - replace tabs with `</td><td>` and new lines with `</tr><tr>` - and add the combo boxes with jquery - but i don't think there is a library for that, nor that it is advisable to do such things in javascript..

Comment: I'd think about loading the data into javascript arrays, rather than an iframe. Do you mean that would be more effective ?

Answer (score -1):

[Here](http://codebeautify.org/excel-to-html) is an online tool for converting Excel spreadsheets into HTML.

Comment: It also sounds like the OP wants a script for doing this, not a web service.